# unable to install ros-kinetic-desktop-full on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, ros

I am trying to install ROS kinetic on 64 bit Ubuntu 18.04. I have run the following commands:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full
```

and I get the following error:

> Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-desktop-full

Moreover, when I run `apt-cache search ros-kinetic` nothing is returned.
I have already checked that my Ubuntu repositories are configured to allow restricted, universe and multiverse

Any advice is greatly appreciated

EDIT: I realize kinetic is not supported for ubuntu bionic but it should still be able to find the package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*ROS Kinetic Kame* is targeted at the Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial). Source build using the steps outlined in [ROS Kinetic wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Source) might be your best option to try to run Kinetic on Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic).

If it doesn't have to be Kinetic but you are happy with a newer release then you just need to wait for one more week (May 23rd, 2018) for [*ROS Melodic Morenia*](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic) release which is targeted at the Ubuntu Bionic.